# Questions about molar ratio

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I am new to chemistry so this might be about a very easy concept that I might be misunderstanding but I would appreciate your help!

I watched a video of combining hydrogen and oxygen and forming water. In the video I watched made sure they had a ratio of 2:1 (2 Hydrogen H2 : 1 oxygen O2) before they put on a fire to  cause the reaction. In my understanding the chemical equation tells us 2 hydrogen molecule and 1 oxygen molecule form 1 water molecule. Sure, you can put stoichiometric numbers to deal with moles of molecules, but even if you don't have this ratio of 2:1, as long as the hydrogen and oxygen molecule in present, shouldn't the reaction between hydrogen and oxygen still occur with having excess hydrogen and oxygen molecules leftover after the formation of water? Can you tell me if I'm wrong?

Also as a side question, is it possible to calculate the exact heat required to cause the chemical reaction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not wrong.

The reaction would still occur if the amounts are not in the specific ratio. The ratio must have been maintained so that they could ensure that almost all the reactant is used. Or if it would be possible to collect the water this formed, the number of moles of water would equal that of hydrogen used (and double of oxygen used).

The particular ratio of reactants is significant when there is possibility of multiple reactions, a popular example being of burning of Carbon, where reducing the amount of available oxygen causes formation of CO as opposed to carbon dioxide (which forms when oxygen is available in high amount).

As for the side question, it is possible to know the amount of heat. You will study it in the thermochemistry topics as you further your knowledge of chemistry.

Comment: Thank you! Is it the same in acid-base and redox titrations? Why won't phenolphthalein react right away when titrant is being added?

Comment: OP is asking about the amount of heat to start the reaction. This is a chain reaction, so you need very little energy, but a high temperature, like a spark.